# Does Metamagic Furious Spell affect Transformation too?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic

New to the game. Learning new things every run through. I currently just went through all of the metamagic feats to find what is best suited for my [orc bloodline sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline). Long term plan is to use fire for damage and control, buffs for the party, and then eventually leverage those buff plus the crazy orc bloodline buffs for myself to go into the thick of battle at later levels.

[Transformation](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/transformation.html) is a key self buff in this bloodline as it is provided via bloodline spells AND enhanced at level 20 via Warlord Reborn. However, it prevents me from casting anything. This is ok because I appreciate being able to cast OR smash things depending on the situation. That's so cool!

Question: Does [metamagic furious spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/furious-spell-metamagic) allow me to cast while under the effects of [Transformation](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/transformation.html)? It's closely related to rage but not exactly the same. I can see the rules going either way.

Also:  Can you think of any way to still cast spells with *transformation* up? Is it possible to end the spell early? What exactly can I still use from my bloodline while transformed? (edited in from comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It does not.**

The barbarian Rage ability and the *rage* spell both prevent you from casting spells because you're too angry to concentrate, but Furious spells can be cast in those states.

*Transformation* basically pretends to change your actual class temporarily, changing your stats and increasing your Base Attack Bonus and Fortitude save as though you only had levels in classes like Fighter or Barbarian - you actually completely lose your spellcasting ability while *transformation* is running, including your ability to cast spells from items like wands, as though you'd never taken a level in sorcerer.  You get your spells back when it wears off, but until then, you are a complete non-caster.

Note that you don't *actually* lose your sorcerer levels (and you retain all of your sorcerer class abilities besides spellcasting); so your bloodline powers and such still work fine.  Also, if you have a familiar (or Improved Familiar) with the share spells ability, you can cast *transformation* and other personal spells on your familiar, and *transformation* does still work even if you don't have spellcasting to trade in for its bonuses.

To answer your related questions:

*Transformation* says you completely lose your spellcasting abilities, including wands and scrolls, as if the spells weren't on your class's spell list.  So, you could theoretically cast spells from wands and scrolls using Use Magic Device, and your racial and/or class-based spell-like abilities will still function.  Just remember you're making the UMD check as though you didn't have spellcasting at all.

*Transformation* isn't dismissable, as there's no (D) in the Duration entry.  You could arrange to have an ally *dispel* or *disjoin* you to break the effect, or move into an *antimagic field* to suppress it.

From your bloodline, you'll retain almost everything except your bonus spells.  Survival as a class skill, any of your bonus feats you've taken, most of your bloodline arcana (the orc subtype, darkvision or extended darkvision, and light sensitivity, though the part about extra damage with spells won't be useful until *transformation* ends. Touch of Rage will still work, the bonuses from Fearless and Strength of the Beast will stay in effect, you can still activate Power of Giants, and your immunity and damage reduction from Warlord Reborn stay, too.  You could even re-cast *transformation* once to prevent it from ending using the *transformation* spell-like ability from Warlord Reborn, assuming you're at least 20th level.

Comment: Thanks fort he clarification. Can you think of any way to still  cast spells with transformation up? Or... is it possible to end the spell early? Lastly, what exactly can I still use from my bloodline while transformed?

Comment: I edited your related questions into your question, and edited my answer to answer them.  They're related enough they can probably fit in the same question. ^_^

Comment: Thanks for all of the info! Guess I just need to make sure I really want to hulk out before casting it.